# "No rows could be found for LocalizedLabel with id <guid> if LocalizedLabel were published"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am getting given below error while importing  Account entity  solution in online ms crm 2011.

"No rows could be found for LocalizedLabel with id  if LocalizedLabel were published"

Regards,

Ramakrishna M

Answer (score 2):

Open SQL and run the next command

```
select * from LocalizedLabel where LocalizedLabelid = 'Guid'
```

if found the records run the next command:

```
delete LocalizedLabel Where LocalizedLabelid = 'Guid'
```

Try to import again and if failed change the command when the LocalizedLabelid from the excel file